# JavaScript mousedown only works on second click

Tags: javascript, onmousedown

I want the buttons to change their color when they're clicked (a darker shade on mousedown and their original color on mouseup) and it works but only on the second click. Why is that? And how can I fix this?

Button id's are 1 through 10 (button1, button2...)

```
document.getElementById('main').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

var buttonNum = e.target.id.substring(6);

if (e.target.id.substring(0,6) === "button") {
  e.target.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {mouseDown(buttonNum)}, false);
  e.target.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {mouseUp(buttonNum)}, false);
  // trying another way:
  // mouseEventHandler(buttonNum);
  result.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML + " was clicked";
}

}, false);

var mouseupColors = ["#CE3737",
                                  "#48935C",
                                  "#FFD454",
                                  "#26567C",
                                  "#FF6528",
                                  "#92898A",
                                  "#AF9FA5",
                                  "#9EA9AA",
                                  "#989788",
                                  "#7C7372"]

var mousedownColors = ["#B52D2D",
                                       "#397A4A",
                                       "#E5BF4B",
                                       "#183F63",
                                       "#E55B24",
                                       "#777071",
                                       "#96888D",
                                       "#879091",
                                       "#7F7E71",
                                       "#635C5B"]

function mouseDown(buttonNum) {
  var buttonId = "button" + buttonNum;
  document.getElementById(buttonId).style.backgroundColor =         mousedownColors[buttonNum - 1];
}

function mouseUp(buttonNum) {
  var buttonId = "button" + buttonNum;
  document.getElementById(buttonId).style.backgroundColor =   mouseupColors[buttonNum - 1];
}
```

I've also tried creating a function that handles mousedown and mouseup. It has the same result.

```
var mouseEventHandler = function(buttonNum) {
  var buttonId = "button" + buttonNum;
  document.getElementById(buttonId).onmousedown = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = mousedownColors[buttonNum - 1];
  };
  document.getElementById(buttonId).onmouseup = function() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = mouseupColors[buttonNum - 1];
  };
};
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lj8kyr7e/

Comment: To avoid all this, have you considered just styling the buttons using their :active pseudo class? The :active state will be added on mousedown for you?

Comment: I have just tried it and it does work. Thanks a lot! Is it best to do this because it makes my code unnecessarily complicated?

Comment: because you add them on the first click? And every click after that you are adding more and more events...

Comment: Generally, you'll want to handle as much styling within your css as possible. Let the browser do the heavy lifting which, in this case, is the logic for applying effects on mousedown.

Comment: Good call on using CSS for that. As a general advice, you should always use the simplest solution possible (that you know). And in this case, it's using CSS pseudo elements.

Comment: Great advice! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`mouseup` and `mousedown` events are registered inside `click` event handler. So the first time the button is clicked, the two events aren't setup yet.

You need to add those events outside of the click handling function. E.g.
https://jsfiddle.net/Lj8kyr7e/6/

Comment: Thanks a lot Coolnalu!